# Activate KAA configuration using Server REST APIs

Tags: kaa

I used kaa rest api for activate my configuration (using Postman), but i have no idea how to fill Parameter content type of configurationId . I have try

```
{
"id" : "98593",
"applicationId": "32769",
"schemaId": "65544" ,
"endpointGroupId": "98308"}
```

but I get HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request, any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i can solve this problem,
You need to set your content-type to application/json and POST body just fill with configuration id

```
curl -v -S -u username:password -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '12423' 'http://localhost:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/activateConfiguration' | python -mjson.tool
```